# How to extract a javascript variable in HTML format to individual value

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML as shown

```
<h6>Hitech</h6><p>Near Cyinet,Hyderabad,Telangana</p>
```

I need to extract all the comma seperated values to the below

```
var locality = Hitech ;
var adddress = Near Cyinet ;
var city = Hyderabad ;
var state = Telangana ;
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i parse the whole string and extract them

Comment: What have you found out and tried so far?

Comment: Just search innertext html and split function in javascript

Comment: You need to seriously think, How to post a question? at-least after 729 question. Can you show what have you tried to solve the problem? Even a worst effort to solve the problem will show your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var val = $('p').text();
var arr = val.split(',');
var locality = $('h6').text();
```

In above answer `arr` will be array having values `'Near Cyinet'` `'Hyderabad'` `'Telangana'` in it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r0koy8jw/ , but i am getting empty values . could you plase tell me why

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have rows that contain your data:

```
<div class="row">
<h6>Hitech</h6><p>Near Cyinet,Hyderabad,Telangana</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<h6>Hitech 2</h6><p>Near Cyinet,Hyderabad,Telangana</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<h6>Hitech 3</h6><p>Near Cyinet,Hyderabad,Telangana</p>
</div>
```

To parse these lines and store values into an array try this:

```
var values = [];

$.each($("div.row"), function(index) {
    var item = $(this);
    var pHtml = $("p", item).html();
    var pHtmlValues = pHtml.split(",");
    var h6Html = $("h6", item).html();
    var value = {
        locality: h6Html,
        adddress: pHtmlValues[0],
        city: pHtmlValues[1],
        state: pHtmlValues[2]
    };
    values.push(value);
});
```

`values` will contain hashtables `{locality: ..., adddress: ..., city: ..., state: ...}` for each row.